# AngularJS, callback and variables scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I m actually facing a problem with javascript in general. In fact, I need to update a list after calling a callback in two different files.

This is my description of the callback :

```
 this.modify = function(){
    var self = this;
    var success = function(){
      self.user = self.userEdit;
    };

    var err = function(data){
      alert(data);
    };

    UserService.put(this.userEdit, success, err);
  }
}
```

And this is the function which calls the callback :

```
 UserService.put = function (data, succ, err) {
        var user = {login:data.login,nom:data.nom,prenom:data.prenom,password:data.password};
        $http({
            url: __ADRS_SRV__ + "user/"+data._id,
            method: "PUT",
            data:user,
            isArray: true
        }).success(function(data){
           succ();
        }).error(function(error){
            err(error);
        });
    }
```

In fact,

```
var success = function(){
      self.user = self.userEdit;
    };
```

doesn't seem to work properly, when I log self.user in the callback call, I got an undefined...

Do you have an idea to bypass this ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember the `this` as `self` before declaring the `success` function:

```
var self = this;
var success = function(){
  self.user = self.userEdit;
};
```

Or an alternative would be just using `this`, but bind the function with `this` variable:

```
var success = function() {
  this.user = this.userEdit;
}.bind(this);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have done this at the top of my code, to dont have to rewrite it every time I have a callback function to manage

Comment: Then it would be better to include those code as well, to free other people from guessing. Is the `this.userEdit` has been cleared somewhere after the `this.modify()` is called?

Comment: Nop, never... If I call console.log(self.user) just before the callback declaration, I have my object. If I log it into my callback function, I have an undefined. I clear nothing nowhere :-/

Comment: Did you mean `console.log(self.userEdit)`?

Comment: Yes I m sorry, this morning is a bit hard :/

Comment: Then I have no idea of what's going on too. Could you setup a plunker to reproduce your problem?